# IBM Cloud Container Registry: How to remove a group (or even all) of images using CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

Checking with "ibmcloud cr images" I see I have several hundred old images in IBM Cloud container registry. Is there a way to delete them all, or delete by date? For example, images older than one year?

(Some shell script will probably do, of course...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options to remove many images at once from the [IBM Cloud Container Registry](https://cloud.ibm.com/registry/overview):

- Go to the [browser console](https://cloud.ibm.com/registry/images), then tick off the all box above the list, optionally deselect individual images, and click **Delete images**.
- Using the command line and the IBM Cloud CLI, you could use `ibmcloud cr image-prune-untagged` ([see here for syntax](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=container-registry-cli-plugin-containerregcli#ic_cr_image_prune_untagged)) to remove all images that are not explicitly tagged.
- First, use something like `ibmcloud cr image-list --format '{{.Repository}}@{{.Digest}}'` to [list all images](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=container-registry-cli-plugin-containerregcli#bx_cr_image_list) and only print the repository and digest. Use this [templating syntax to filter](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_cli_list) on some properties to reduce the list. Then, use that output list as input for `ibmcloud cr image-rm` ([syntax](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=container-registry-cli-plugin-containerregcli#bx_cr_image_rm)).